# How to create a symmetric key for CryptDecrypt using raw hex key values in Windows CryptoAPI?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cryptoapi

After a lot of trial-and-error, I was able to successfully encrypt a file with an AES-256 key using the Windows `CryptoAPI`.

The encryption program does the following:

- Fixes block length to 128 bits (`AES`)
- Generates an AES-256-CBC key (`CryptGenKey`)
- Encrypts file using this key (`CryptEncrypt`)

Now in order to decrypt the file, I want to use the key that I have in raw hex values format. For example, I have this key:

> 76FD3DBDFA2AA07113A227D9E0311DC5BC7FA78A7E4FC3CE63919B9C49DC4F06

(Note that this key is randomly [generated online](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/keygen) just as an example and is not used anywhere to secure anything)

All I have is the raw hex value of the key as shown above. So I need to be able to feed it to the `CryptDecrypt` function and decrypt data. **Problem is:**

[CryptDecrypt expects the key to be sent in as an HCRYPTKEY data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecrypt). But all I have is a key stored in this format:

```
wchar_t* key = argv[1]  //reading the key in hex format as an argument
```

**What I have tried:**

[CryptDeriveKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptderivekey) to derive the key in HCRYPTKEY format from a base value. However, CryptDeriveKey will not accept my key in the hex values format that I currently have it in since it, in turn, needs the key in HCRYPTHASH format.

At this point, I'm not sure how I can use the raw hex values I have as a key for CryptDecrypt to decrypt the data. I know it's possible, I just don't know how to get there.

For reasons I won't get into, I *must* derive the key from the raw hex values that I have (as opposed to any other key format such as a byte array) and feed it to `CryptDecrypt` to decrypt data.

Answer (score 1):

You should import key with [CryptImportKey function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptimportkey).

```
BOOL CryptImportKey(
  HCRYPTPROV hProv,
  const BYTE *pbData,
  DWORD      dwDataLen,
  HCRYPTKEY  hPubKey,
  DWORD      dwFlags,
  HCRYPTKEY  *phKey
);
```

hProv - the handle of a CSP obtained with the CryptAcquireContext function.
hPubKey - in your case must be 0.
dwFlags - in your case must be 0.
phKey - resulting key, that CryptDecrypt expected.

And here is some tricky part. **pbData** must contains  [BLOBHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/ns-wincrypt-_publickeystruc) structure followed by key value.

```
typedef struct _PUBLICKEYSTRUC {
  BYTE   bType;
  BYTE   bVersion;
  WORD   reserved;
  ALG_ID aiKeyAlg;
} BLOBHEADER, PUBLICKEYSTRUC;

bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB (0x08) - in your case  
bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION (0x02) 
reserved = 0  
aiKeyAlg = algorithm id which you used in CryptGenKey
```

Sample code:

```
BYTE key_value[] = { 0x76, 0xFD, 0x3D, 0xBD, 0xFA, 0x2A, 0xA0, 0x71, 0x13, 0xA2, 0x27, 0xD9, 0xE0, 0x31, 0x1D, 0xC5, 
    0xBC, 0x7F, 0xA7, 0x8A, 0x7E, 0x4F, 0xC3, 0xCE, 0x63, 0x91, 0x9B, 0x9C, 0x49, 0xDC, 0x4F, 0x06 };
BLOBHEADER bh;
bh.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
bh.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
bh.reserved = 0;
bh.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_256;

DWORD dwDataLen = sizeof(key_value) + sizeof(bh);
BYTE* pbData = (BYTE*)malloc(dwDataLen);
BYTE* ptr = pbData;
memcpy(ptr, (BYTE*)&bh, sizeof(bh));
ptr += sizeof(bh);
memcpy(ptr, key_value, sizeof(key_value));
if (!CryptImportKey(hProv, pbData, dwDataLen, 0, 0, &hKey)) {
    return GetLastError();
}
```